# How i find neo4j cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

I'm trying to implement Friend Recommend.

Its starts from Node"You". And, I want to find Node"Anna".

In other words, It's a person whom two or more of my friends know in common. And example node of above is Anna.

I'd appreciate if your help.

node: Person

relationship: Friendship

```
MATCH (neo:Person {name: "You"})-[*2]->(target:Person)
MATCH (neo)-[:FRIENDSHIP]->(friend:Person)
MATCH (target)-[rel:FRIENDSHIP]->(friend)
WHERE target.name <> "You"
RETURN rel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you only need a Person node that would like to recommend.
Here is how you can proceed in 2 steps:

**Step-1. Find Persons (friend-of-friend) and count of common friends:**

```
MATCH path=(neo:Person {name: "You"})-[:RELATED_TO*2]->(target:Person) 
WHERE target <> neo
WITH neo, target, count(path) as cf 
RETURN target, cf
```

**Step-2. Filter Persons who have 2 or more friends in common:**

```
MATCH path=(neo:Person {name: "You"})-[:RELATED_TO*2]->(target:Person) 
WHERE target <> neo
WITH neo, target, count(path) as cf 
WITH target WHERE cf >= 2
RETURN target, cf
```

Comment: That's works for me. Thanks.
But neo4j browser announced that CYPHER "path=(  )-[  ]->(  )" will be removed in future versions. Is therer any query to replace it?

Comment: Fixed it. Colon was missing